# ¿Cómo puedo mantener la selección de un texto tras hacer click en un botón?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

estoy intentando hacer un editor de texto en el que tras seleccionar el texto deseado pueda convertirlo en negrita pulsando un botón en específico. El problema viene cuando pulso el botón, que todo el texto se deselecciona.

En este caso lo que quiero es pulsar el botón `id="btn_negrita"` y que el texto que tenga seleccionado en el textarea se mantenga seleccionado. Necesito saber como implementar el código JS para conseguir eso.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="editor.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- <script src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <title>Editor HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contenedor">
        <div id="contenedor_editor">
            <div id="cabecera" class="ancho_cabeceras dp-flex">
                <span class="estilo-span btn_princ" id="btn_negrita">N</span>
                <span class="estilo-span btn_princ" id="cursiva">K</span>
                <span class="estilo-span btn_princ" id="enlace">E</span>
                <span class="estilo-span btn_princ" id="bloque">BL</span>
                <span class="estilo-span btn_princ" id="codigo">COD</span>
                <span class="estilo-span btn_princ" id="imagen">IMG</span>
                <span class="estilo-span btn_princ" id="deshacer">DESHACER</span>
                <span class="estilo-span btn_princ" id="rehacer">REHACER</span>
            </div>
            <div id="cabecera2" class="ancho_cabeceras">
                
            </div>
            <div id="editor">
                <textarea contenteditable="true" name="" id="editor_txt" cols="300" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div id="contenedor_muestra" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="editor.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *Necesito saber como implementar el código JS para conseguir eso* -> Pues... escribiéndolo en un archivo .js, como tu `editor.js`. Ahora, si lo que quieres es que hagamos el código por ti y te demos algo que directamente te funcione con copiarlo y pegarlo, te estás equivocando de sitio... Te recomiendo que antes de nada **intentes hacerlo tú mismo**. Y si investigas un poco, verás que ya existen múltiples preguntas al respecto en google... (y en SO, claro). Algunas con [solución](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880271/make-selected-text-bold-unbold)

Comment: ¿Y el contenido de `editor.js`? Necesitamos ver el código que estás usando para ver cómo lo haces y poder aconsejarte la manera correcta de hacerlo. PD: Imagino que sé qué te falla, al sustituir el contenido del campo se restablece la selección. Te aconsejo que consultes esto: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Selection

Answer (score -2):

Te recomiendo que leas esta web acerca de almacenar el texto seleccionado:

[Detectar texto seleccionado](https://lineadecodigo.com/jquery/detectar-texto-seleccionado-con-jquery/#:%7E:text=El%20m%C3%A9todo%20de%20jQuery%20que%20nos%20ayudar%C3%A1%20a,texto%20seleccionado.%20En%20nuestro%20c%C3%B3digo%20el%20textarea%20%E2%80%98texto%E2%80%99.)

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.